# can't disable cell based on background color swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift2, cell

I am making an app that uses different colored cells to separate cells into different categories, but I also have a function that allows the user to tap on cells to add checkmarks and select them. I would like the colored cells to be disabled so that when the user taps on them they don't add a checkmark to the cell and select it.
this is my checkmark function:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cellIdentifier = "instrumentTableCell"
    let cell: InstrumentTableCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as? InstrumentTableCell

    checked = Array(count:recipies.count, repeatedValue:false)
    cell.configurateTheCell(recipies[indexPath.row])

    if !checked[indexPath.row] {
        cell.accessoryType = .None
    } else if checked[indexPath.row] {
        cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    }


    return cell
}
```

Comment: Does `cell.userInteractionEnabled` help?

Comment: @paulvs yep that worked thanks!

Comment: I added it as an answer.

Comment: If you're happy with an answer, you can mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check mark on the left of the post.

Answer (score 1):

Try `cell.userInteractionEnabled = false`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the UITableViewDelegate function

```
tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:
```

You can access cell features such as font and background color there:

```
cell.backgroundColor
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor
cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor
```

Based on the color, you can then enable/disable the cell for tapping using

```
cell.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

If necessary, you can enable/disable other parts of the cell here as well.